# WebService times out, but client receives no exception

Tags: java, web-services

I have an application that is attempting to call a service and the other service appears to be timing out. The problem is my application does not receive any timeout exceptions, although I do see an error printed out to the console:

```
[7/8/13 12:39:32:360 EDT] 00000005 TimeoutManage I   WTRN0006W: Transaction 0000013FBF252E43000000010000000CE81CB4935851D5C13DECD3DBB2D463F0DBECAEE60000013FBF252E43000000010000000CE81CB4935851D5C13DECD3DBB2D463F0DBECAEE600000001 has timed out after 120 seconds.
[7/8/13 12:39:32:360 EDT] 00000005 TimeoutManage I   WTRN0124I: When the timeout occurred the thread with which the transaction is, or was most recently, associated was Thread[WebContainer : 1,5,main]. The stack trace of this thread when the timeout occurred was: 
    java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:196)
    com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.waitForCompletion(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:334)
    com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.getByteCount(AsyncFuture.java:218)
    com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioSocketIOChannel.readAIOSync(AioSocketIOChannel.java:215)
    com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioTCPReadRequestContextImpl.processSyncReadRequest(AioTCPReadRequestContextImpl.java:182)
    com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.TCPReadRequestContextImpl.read(TCPReadRequestContextImpl.java:111)
    com.ibm.ws.http.channel.outbound.impl.HttpOutboundServiceContextImpl.parseResponseMessageSync(HttpOutboundServiceContextImpl.java:1657)
    com.ibm.ws.http.channel.outbound.impl.HttpOutboundServiceContextImpl.readSyncResponse(HttpOutboundServiceContextImpl.java:725)
    com.ibm.ws.http.channel.outbound.impl.HttpOutboundServiceContextImpl.startResponseReadSync(HttpOutboundServiceContextImpl.java:1775)
    com.ibm.ws.http.channel.outbound.impl.HttpOutboundServiceContextImpl.finishRequestMessage(HttpOutboundServiceContextImpl.java:1195)
    com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.out.HttpOutSyncWriter.finishBufferRequest(HttpOutSyncWriter.java:94)
    com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.out.HttpOutWriter.writeBuffer(HttpOutWriter.java:136)
    com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.out.HttpOutByteBufferOutputStream.finish(HttpOutByteBufferOutputStream.java:468)
    com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.SOAPOverHTTPSender.sendChunkedRequest(SOAPOverHTTPSender.java:890)
    com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.SOAPOverHTTPSender.sendSOAPRequest(SOAPOverHTTPSender.java:807)
    com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.SOAPOverHTTPSender.send(SOAPOverHTTPSender.java:611)
    com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.HTTPTransportSender.invoke(HTTPTransportSender.java:364)
    org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:531)
    org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:401)
    org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:228)
    org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:163)
    org.apache.axis2.jaxws.core.controller.impl.AxisInvocationController.execute(AxisInvocationController.java:581)
    org.apache.axis2.jaxws.core.controller.impl.AxisInvocationController.doInvoke(AxisInvocationController.java:130)
    org.apache.axis2.jaxws.core.controller.impl.InvocationControllerImpl.invoke(InvocationControllerImpl.java:93)
    org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invokeSEIMethod(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:364)
    org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invoke(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:185)
```

The client is created with these settings:

```
bindProvider.getRequestContext().put(com.ibm.wsspi.webservices.Constants.RESPONSE_TIMEOUT_PROPERTY , connectionProperties.getProperty(MyService.TIME_OUT));
bindProvider.getRequestContext().put(com.ibm.wsspi.webservices.Constants.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_PROPERTY , connectionProperties.getProperty(MyService.TIME_OUT));
bindProvider.getRequestContext().put(com.ibm.wsspi.webservices.Constants.READ_TIMEOUT_PROPERTY , connectionProperties.getProperty(MyService.TIME_OUT));
```

`MyService.TIME_OUT` has a value of 20000 and I have verified that it is being set correctly.

The code that catches calls the service looks like this:

```
try
{
    response = ((MyServicePortType) myService).doWebServiceOperation(request);
}
catch (Throwable e) //I know, catch Throwable is not very good but right now I'd be happy to catch ANYthing here!
{

    log.error("Webservice reported error",e);
}
```

Even though I've changed my `catch` block to catch *anything*, I still don't catch any exceptions. WebSphere detects a transaction timeout, but I don't know why the application doesn't detect a timeout in the web service call. Is there something I'm missing that would cause a proper timeout exception to be thrown so that I can catch it and send the message to the application framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well now I feel silly.

It seems that for WebSphere, these properties (`RESPONSE_TIMEOUT_PROPERTY`, `CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_PROPERTY`, etc...)   should have their values set in **seconds**, and I was using **milliseconds** based on what I'd seen in online examples (that clearly were not intended for WebSphere).

Changing `20000` to `20` has resolved this problem.

The page that suggested I should be assuming seconds instead of milliseconds is this one: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/rwbs_httptransportprop.html